# Where did the 2nd level of maven java compiler error information go when I updated to java7?

Tags: maven, java-7

When using java6 I saw two levels of error information

- The error: file:[line,char] error: cannot find symbol
- Details: symbol: method ....  location: class com.....

Now, that I updated to java7 I no longer have this information.  If I compile manually using "-Xlint:all" I see the details.  For some reason maven isn't displaying the details.

Please let me know if you have any ideas how to fix this.

Thanks

Peter

**Good using Java 6**

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] warntest/src/main/java/com/attivio/foo/App.java:[9,1] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DoesNotExistType
location: class com.foo.App
```

**Less Information using Java 7**

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] warntest/src/main/java/com/attivio/foo/App.java:[9,1] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 1 error
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-158